Log4j Logs Are Not Showing In The Console
I have a Spring Boot Gradle project and I'm trying to configure the logging aspect to display logs in the console. However, when I run my application, the logs do not appear, and I am unable to determine the cause of this issue. I am not sure if there is a misconfiguration in my logging setup or if I am overlooking some crucial settings. Despite following the usual steps to enable console logging, the problem persists. Can someone help me identify what might be wrong or guide me through the correct configuration process?
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.base'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.3.0'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.1'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.1'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'com.base.BaseDependencies.BaseDependenciesApplication'
    )
  }
}

Aspect Class
package com.base.BaseDependencies.Aspects;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    
    @Pointcut("within(com.base.BaseDependencies.*)")
    public void generalPointCutLogger() {}
    
    @Before("generalPointCutLogger()")
    public void logMethodInitialization(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodArguments = Arrays.toString(jp.getArgs());
        log.info("{} successfully invoked with arguments {}", getClassAndMethodName(jp), methodArguments);
    }
    
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "generalPointCutLogger()", returning = "response")
    public void logMethodResponse(JoinPoint jp, Object response) {
        log.info("{} successfully returned with response {}", getClassAndMethodName(jp), response);
    }
    
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "generalPointCutLogger()", throwing = "exception")
    public void logMethodException(JoinPoint jp, Throwable exception) {
        String exceptionName = exception.getClass().getName();
        log.error("{} thrown in {} with message: {}", exceptionName, getClassAndMethodName(jp),
                exception.getMessage());
    }
    
    public String getClassAndMethodName(JoinPoint jp) {
        return String.format("%s -> %s", jp.getTarget().getClass(), jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
    

}

Log4j Properties File
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %m%n

Main Class
package com.base.BaseDependencies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class BaseDependenciesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BaseDependenciesApplication.class, args);
        log.info("Apllication Started Successfully");
    }

}


Apart the errors in your configuration file (you are using Log4j 1 syntax, not Log4j 2 syntax) that were corrected in @Ruslan's answer, your code seems Ok. Check also the log4j-samples-aspectj example on how to use the flow tracing and source location injection features of Log4j API.

What is the name of your properties file? Make sure that it corresponds to the following name: log4j2.properties and it's located in the right directory: src/main/resources
Please also make sure that you specify all the settings following the documentation:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html
Example:
# The root logger with appender name
rootLogger = INFO, STDOUT

# Assign STDOUT a valid appender & define its layout
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


Hello, the name of my properties file is log4j2.properties. When I specify the same settings that you did above only the start-up logs show but anything after that doesn't for example when I hit an endpoint the logs are supposed to show in the console but they don't could this be an issue with my aspect class?

I would comment out the aspect logging class for testing purpose and remove Lombok annotation @Log4j2, try to specify the logger explicitly after it and check again.
Something like this:
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NameOfYourClass.class);
Make sure that log4j2 dependency is indeed in your classpath.

log4j-core and log4j-api dependencies should be in your classpath.

There is no Logger#getLogger method in Log4j 2 API. You must be either using Log4j 1 or java.util.logging.

You are right, I indeed used Log4j.

Log4j2 is using  LogManager instead of Logger, but the logic is pretty much the same.
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class);

I did comment out the @Log4j2 annotation and the Log4j2 is indeed inside my classpath but even with the  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class) i still get the startup logs and nothing after that

I've reproduced this using a spring boot project where I specified all the dependencies based on your build.gradle file except jpa dependency. Everything is working as a charm even without an explicit log4j2.properties file. Later I also provided the config file explicitly and it also worked if the config is correct and the console appender was provided. Try to obliterate the configuration file and rerun it, if it's not working something is off on your side.
